# Excluding css from sub class on ul

Tags: css

Trying to apply the following css padding and shadow to all the main menus but not the sub-menu.  I've tried a large combination of descendant and using the :not() to no luck.. heads a bit spinning at this point, hence the request for assistance.  you can see at http://www.thefruitnation.com/ I am trying to keep the shadow applied to the top menu navigation but not have it show in the slight green outline on the sub menu dropdowns.

Basically just trying to exclude  .sub-menu when I apply the following to #access a {}

Thanks for any assistance

```
#access>.menu-menu-1-container>.menu a:not(.sub-menu) {
padding: 3px 10px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #004700;
}


<nav id="access">
            <a class="nav-show" href="#access">Show Navigation</a>
            <a class="nav-hide" href="#nogo">Hide Navigation</a>
            <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
            <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-499" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-499"><a href="#" style="height: 43px;">Intentions<br> <span>and projects</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
<li id="menu-item-400" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-400"><a title="more inside" href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-509" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-509"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/tfn-fruit-exchange/">TFN Fruit Exchange</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-515" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-515"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/tfn-public-nursery/">TFN Public Nursery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-520" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-520"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/tfn-workshops/">TFN Workshops</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-401" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-401"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/articles/" style="height: 43px;">Articles<br> <span>read on</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-402" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-402"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/festival/" style="height: 43px;">Festival<br> <span>Sacramento 2014</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-405" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-405"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/shop/" style="height: 43px;">Shop<br> <span>help support us</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-475" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-475"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/forums/" style="height: 43px;">Forums<br> <span>Join In!</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-480" class="bp-menu bp-activity-nav menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-480"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/members/admin/activity/" style="height: 43px;">Your Activity<br> <span>Get busy!</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-490" class="bp-menu bp-profile-nav menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-490"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/members/admin/profile/">Profile</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-487" class="bp-menu bp-settings-nav menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-487">
<a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/members/admin/settings/">Settings</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li><li id="menu-item-485" class="bp-menu bp-notifications-nav menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-485"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/members/admin/notifications/">Notifications</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-484" class="bp-menu bp-messages-nav menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-484"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/members/admin/messages/">Messages</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-482" class="bp-menu bp-friends-nav menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-482"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/members/admin/friends/">Friends</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-483" class="bp-menu bp-groups-nav menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-483"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/members/admin/groups/">Groups</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-489" class="bp-menu bp-forums-nav menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-489"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/members/admin/forums/">Forums</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-488" class="bp-menu bp-logout-nav menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-488"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefruitnation.com&amp;_wpnonce=0b1597a0af">Log Out</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-527" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-527"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/fruity-friends/" style="height: 43px;">Fruity Friends<br> <span>featured</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-528" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-528"><a href="http://www.thefruitnation.com/fruity-faq/" style="height: 43px;">Fruity FAQ</a></li>
</ul></div>             <div class="clear"></div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you where almost there!

problem was that your style is applying on every `<a>` inside `.menu`
and `:not(.sub-menu)` was looking for `<a class="sub-menu"...>`

try like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xfSqZ/

```
#access > .menu-menu-1-container > .menu > li > a {
    padding: 3px 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #004700;
}
```

also note if there are NOT any other .menu classes this will do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/xfSqZ/1/

```
.menu > li > a {
    padding: 3px 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #004700;
}
```

Comment: First one did the trick, 2nd one doesnt collapse it like I was after.  Thanks Caramba.. I figured I was leaving li or ul out of there somewhere, after trying all the keys you get sort of jaded haha.  thanks again

Comment: @user3312912 you are welcome, glad it helped! please accept the answer as the right one and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

For any kind of style inheritance, nested elements can be 'reset' or overwritten simply like :

**CSS**

```
div { border:1px solid green; }
div div { border:1px solid red; }
div div div { border:0; }
```

*-- just a space between each level*

**MARKUP**

```
<div> GREEN BORDER
  <div>  RED BORDER
    <div>  NO BORDER </div>
  </div>
</div>
```